# How to set column's +comment+ with CREATE TABLE and SELECT statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to set **comments** on columns of tables so then when the user selects a column from the table, the comment has to be displayed so that client will be aware this column is used for this reason.

Can any suggest how would I achieve this in SQL?

Below mention create table script and comment to be add on

```
CREATE TABLE dw.netsuite_pif_transactions
(
trans_id int primary key not null identity(1,1),
batch_id char(60) NOT NULL,
transaction_date datetime NOT NULL,
vendor_id char(15) NOT NULL,
product char(31) NOT NULL,
member_id char(15) NOT NULL,
transaction_type varchar(5) NOT NULL,
units numeric(9) NOT NULL,
value numeric(9) NOT NULL,
currency varchar(5) NOT NULL,
external_reference char(17) NOT NULL,
interface_date datetime NOT NULL,
date_created datetime
);
```

-- ****** Columns Description ********

```
-- trans_id - Auto Generated Unique Id to reference transactions
-- batch_id - Batch Id of the All Transactions processed on an individual Run
-- transaction_date - Date of Transaction
-- vendor_id - ID of Vendor
```

Comment: You can add comment at the time of table creation or alteration either using SSMS or script. But it'll not show at the time of table column selection. But if anyone can show the table structure then s/he will show description.

Comment: Thanks, Rahul for your suggestion.